# Phusion Passenger on shared server

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, deployment, passenger

Does anyone have any advice on fixing Passenger's slow initial load on a shared server? I typically work with engineyard and their lovely gem, which makes deploying much easier. I'm wondering if anyone has advice on how to speed Passenger up OR advice on switching from Passenger to something else.

Are there any Passenger alternatives that wont have the same initial delay issues?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have access to Passenger configuration, I believe that `PassengerPreStart` option is much better than `wget`.

http://www.modrails.com/documentation/Users%20guide%20Apache.html#PassengerPreStart

Answer (score 1):

Unicorn supports zero-downtime deploys and hot-swaps your code, so startup time is much faster.

Just be sure to put "unicorn" in your Gemfile.

Answer (score 0):

If you have access to cron you can run a wget or curl script to make sure the server stays awake.

Comment: Do you know of any common or popular script I could run?